Change pictureSize/ratio with expo-camera
I'm using expo-camera (CameraView to be precise) to take pictures in portrait mode of landscapes styles pictures. By doing so when I rotate them to visualize them in landscape, the height is very small compared to the width.
I'm trying to arrive to a result of 4:3 like for Iphone for exemple but I don't succeed in changing the ratio/pictureSize of the photos I'm taking.
This is my code:
// CameraScreen.js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { CameraView, useCameraPermissions, getAvailablePictureSizesAsync } from 'expo-camera';

export default function CameraScreen({ navigation }) {
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();
  const [isTakingPicture, setIsTakingPicture] = useState(false);
  const [enableTorch, setEnableTorch] = useState(false);

  if (!permission) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.permissionContainer}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
        <Button title="Grant Permission" onPress={requestPermission} />          
      </View>
    );
  }

  const takePicture = async () => {
    setIsTakingPicture(true);
    const photo = await camera.takePictureAsync( { pictureSize: '640x480', quality: 0.5 });
    navigation.navigate('ImagePreview', { photo });
    setIsTakingPicture(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CameraView
          style={styles.camera}
          type='back'
          flashMode='auto'
          pictureSize='640x480'
          ratio='640x480'
          enableTorch={enableTorch}
          ref={(ref) => {
            camera = ref;
          }}
          onCameraReady={() => {
            setEnableTorch(false);
          }}
        >
          <Button title="Photo" onPress={takePicture} />
        </CameraView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});


the ratio, pictureSize, as props or as options for takePictureAsync() don't work wether I put '4/3' or '640x480'.
When using getAvailablePictureSizesAsyncI get this result
0: "3840x2160"
1: "1920x1080"
2: "1280x720"
3: "640x480"
4: "352x288"
5: "Photo"
6: "High"
7: "Medium"
8: "Low"

Moreover I need to also set the same ratio for any mobile phone that will use the camera, so how can I take a size from the getAvailablePictureSizesAsync if this might not be an option on another mobile phone?
Thank you.
